# Need to check existence of flag in GNUmakefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am checking for existence of flag that is passed by user to GNUmakefile.

Basically, i am checking whether user has passed `-j` in my makefile. I have added below `if` condition. But before that i am trying to display `MAKEFLAGS` where i can see output is empty for that variable.

```
ifneq (,$(findstring j,$(MAKEFLAGS)))
 ....
```

Am i missing anything here?

Sometimes users may also pass `--jobs` instead of `-j` , And also i need to check whether the value passed to `-j/--jobs` is greater than `2`

Is there any easy way in GNUmake for doing so in single if condition ?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question depends on what version of GNU make you're using.

If you're using GNU make 4.1 or below, then the answer is "no, it's not possible" from within a makefile (of course you can always write a shell script wrapper around make and check the arguments before invoking make).

If you're using GNU make 4.2 or above, then the answer is "yes, it's quite possible".  See this entry from the [GNU make NEWS](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/NEWS) file:

> Version 4.2 (22 May 2016)
>
> - The amount of parallelism can be determined by querying MAKEFLAGS, even when
>   the job server is enabled (previously MAKEFLAGS would always contain only
>   "-j", with no number, when job server was enabled).

Comment: It doesn't matter what version of GCC you're using.  It depends on what version of GNU make you're using.  They are different projects and have different release cycles, and although they are often used together they are not really related, and can be used completely separately as well.  Use `make --version` to see the version of GNU make you're using.

Comment: OK.  GNU make 3.81 was released in April 2006, so you're definitely missing most modern features of GNU make.  Sorry, but you're out of luck WRT implementing this inside your makefile.  If you want it to be done with GNU make 3.81 your only option is to write a wrapper script to be invoked instead of running `make` directly, and implementing your check in that wrapper script then setting a variable when your script invokes `make`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question because `MAKEFLAGS` is a very strange make variable. First of all, with GNU make 4.3, `-jN`, `-j N`, `--jobs N` and `--jobs=N` are all converted to `-jN` in `MAKEFLAGS`, which looks interesting. You could thus try something like:

```
J := $(patsubst -j%,%,$(filter -j%,$(MAKEFLAGS)))
```

to get the `N` value passed on the command line or the empty string if `-j` and `--jobs` have not been used. But then, if you try the following you will see that it is not the whole story:

```
$ cat Makefile
.PHONY: all

J := $(patsubst -j%,%,$(filter -j%,$(MAKEFLAGS)))

ifneq ($(J),4)
all:
    @echo MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    @echo patsubst...=$(patsubst -j%,%,$(filter -j%,$(MAKEFLAGS)))
    @echo J=$(J)
else
all:
    @echo J=4
endif
$ make -j4
MAKEFLAGS= -j4 -l8 --jobserver-auth=3,4
patsubst...=4
J=
```

Apparently `MAKEFLAGS` is not set when the Makefile is parsed (and the `J` make variable is assigned the empty string) but it is when the recipes are executed. So, using `MAKEFLAGS` with conditionals does not work. But if you can move your tests in a recipe, something like the following could work:

```
.PHONY: all

all:
    j=$(patsubst -j%,%,$(filter -j%,$(MAKEFLAGS))); \
    if [ -n "$$j" ] && [ $$j -gt 2 ]; then \
        <do something>; \
    else \
        <do something else>; \
    fi
```

Or:

```
.PHONY: all

J = $(patsubst -j%,%,$(filter -j%,$(MAKEFLAGS)))

all:
    @if [ -n "$(J)" ] && [ $(J) -gt 2 ]; then \
        <do something>; \
    else \
        <do something else>; \
    fi
```

Note the use of the recursively expanded variable assignment (`J = ...`) instead of simple assignment (`J := ...`).

Comment: Thanks! I am trying your first example. I am passing '-j 2' to my make command :- make -j 2 all , Nothing is getting displayed for variable MAKEFLAGS. I need to check 'j' integer value and proceed with target execution if it is greater than 2. Your second example shows that , inside target we are checking the 'j' value.

Comment: Yes, the first example shows than trying to drive conditionals with `MAKEFLAGS` does not work. The 2 other examples show how to use it in recipes.

Comment: Actually, if user passes -j<3> , I wanted to run the pre-reqs of target 'all' in parallel. Here checking variable J value inside 'all' target wont help right ? Note:- all has two pre-reqs all1 all2 which needs to run parallel ,when user passed greater than 2 for j while run time.

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you invoke `make -jN all` with `N>=2` and `all` depends on `all1` and `all2`, make will probably try to build `all1` and `all2` in parallel by default. Why do you want to check the value of the `-j` option if make already does what you want?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Actually i want to run 'all2' with adding some delay. Because there is some stuff which we create from all1 is dependent on all2.

Comment: @kunal  If you do not properly declare your dependencies you should probably reconsider using make. Because if you fight make instead of letting it help you, you will probably encounter many difficulties. If `allX` depends on `allY` tell make about it and it will do what's best, using parallel build when it makes sense, not using it when it should not be used.